# .Net Web Api - ArrayBuffer mess up with other api calls

Tags: .net, http, asp.net-web-api, response, httpresponsemessage

I have a couple of web api controller functions that look like the following

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCycle")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCycle(string type) {
        try
        {
            Cycle oCycleClass = Data.GetCycle(type);
            return Request.CreateResponse(oCycleClass);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

This is another controller that works as expected.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("GetDataDownload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDataExport([FromBody]DataObject objectData)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] excelData = Data.GetDataExport(objectData);

            String timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH mm ss");

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(excelData);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "DataExport - " + focalData.User.ID + " - " + timeStamp + ".xlsx";

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The error comes after I execute any other controller after the `GetDataExport` function. It looks like the `HttpResponseMessage` gets somehow corrupted.

**For example:**

**1.** Execute `GetCycle` - Result: *Success*

**2.** Execute `GetDataExport` - Result: *Success*

**3.** Execute `GetCycle` - Result: *Fail*

---

`GetDataExport` function below

```
public static byte[] GetDataExport(DataObject dataObject)
    {
        DataTable view = Common.ConvertToDataTable<View>(dataObject.Views);
        string filter = Common.ConvertFiltersToSQLStatement(dataObject.Filters);

        DataSet ds;

        if (dataObject.DownloadWithFilters)
        {
            ds = InterfaceDataClass.GetEmployees(dataObject.CycleId, view, filter, 1, 0, true);
        }
        else
        {
            ds = InterfaceDataClass.GetEmployees(dataObject.CycleId, view, string.Empty, 1, 0, true);
        }

        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employees");

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(ds.Tables[0], true);

            //Format the header column
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:BB1"])
            {
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(122, 122, 122));
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.WhiteSmoke);
            }

            return pck.GetAsByteArray();
        }
    }
```

The `ExcelPackage` comes from a library called `EPPlus`

Comment: Is there any error logged?? Also, make sure that you are closing the resources carefully.

Comment: What would be the correct way to close the resources?

Comment: I guess you are accessing some file stream, please close that in that case. Also if you can share code of GetDataExport method, that would be helpful

Comment: I'm not using streams.

Comment: Please post GetDataExport method code in question for further help

Comment: I just added the `GetDataExport` function.

Answer (score 0):

The API had no mistake at all. The issue was in the way how the API was being called and executed.